# Print seconds without fractional part in GNU find

Tags: shell, find

With `%TS` it always outputs the fractional part. Is there a way to get rid of the fractional part?

```
find ./ -type f -printf "%TY%Tm%Td-%TH%TM%TS %P\n"
20200813-133459.6920994010 export.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can discard the decimal part by specifying a precision of two bytes.

```
%.2TS
```

Comment: Note: this prints the first n characters of the formatted field. the `.2` should ***not suggest*** any *numerical* formatting of the fractional part.